# perl6 Passing operators as arguments

Tags: parameters, arguments, operators, raku

I am trying to achieve some functionality similar to Scheme by defining and passing raw operators. In Scheme, you can

```
(define x +) (x 1 2)
```

and this operation will give you answer 3. In perl6, I somehow have to place the operator in another function in order to achieve the same:

```
sub x($a) { $a * 2; }
sub y($m, $n) { $m($n); }
say y(&x, 3); # gives you 6
say y(+, 3) # this is error
```

Is there an easy way to pass operators and functions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't do Scheme, but

```
(define x +)
```

should correspond to something like

```
my constant &x = &infix:<+>;
```

Then,

```
say x(1,2)
```

will output 3 as well.

There's also a shorthand notation `&[+]` for passing operators around if you find the canonical name used above too cumbersome.

Note that I'm not entirely sure what you were trying to do with your Perl6 code, as that looks rather different from the Scheme snippet.

Comment: Thank you Christoph !! "constant" and "&[+]" are both new concepts to me. I learned something today ! Thank you !!